# Chosen JS - Add the optgroup to the selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I want to find the way to enter the optgroup label into the inserted search-choice item, when the user select a option. With the format `[optgroup]-[option]`.

The problem is that by default there is no a clear way to do it.
Any suggestions on how to achieve this behavior?

Thank you in advance.

### This is the default behavior

[image]

### This is what I am trying to do

[image: Chosen JS]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093048/jquery-get-label-of-optgroup-of-select-option this should help you if I guess your need correctly...

Comment: That's not exactly what I am trying to do, because the select is a Chosen JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrHDH/260/)**

You can achieve that by receiving a second parameter of `on()` method that contains an object with an attribute `selected` contains a `value` element  if it exists or the `text` element (like the current case) :

```
$(".chosen-select").on('change', function (event,el) {
```

Then you can get the closest `optgroup` and concatenate the both then update the option `text` :

```
var selected_value  = selected_element.val();
var parent_optgroup = selected_element.closest('optgroup').attr('label');

selected_element.text(parent_optgroup+' - '+selected_value).trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Check example below, Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(".chosen-select").chosen();

$(".chosen-select").on('change', function (event,el) {
  var selected_element = $(".chosen-select option:contains("+el.selected+")");
  
  var selected_value  = selected_element.val();
  var parent_optgroup = selected_element.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
  
  selected_element.text(parent_optgroup+' - '+selected_value).trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<select multiple data-placeholder="example" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="5">
  <option value=""></option>
  <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
    <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
    <option>New York Giants</option>
    <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
    <option>Washington Redskins</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
    <option>Chicago Bears</option>
    <option>Detroit Lions</option>
    <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
    <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="NFC SOUTH">
    <option>Atlanta Falcons</option>
    <option>Carolina Panthers</option>
    <option>New Orleans Saints</option>
    <option>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="NFC WEST">
    <option>Arizona Cardinals</option>
    <option>St. Louis Rams</option>
    <option>San Francisco 49ers</option>
    <option>Seattle Seahawks</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="AFC EAST">
    <option>Buffalo Bills</option>
    <option>Miami Dolphins</option>
    <option>New England Patriots</option>
    <option>New York Jets</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="AFC NORTH">
    <option>Baltimore Ravens</option>
    <option>Cincinnati Bengals</option>
    <option>Cleveland Browns</option>
    <option>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="AFC SOUTH">
    <option>Houston Texans</option>
    <option>Indianapolis Colts</option>
    <option>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
    <option>Tennessee Titans</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="AFC WEST">
    <option>Denver Broncos</option>
    <option>Kansas City Chiefs</option>
    <option>Oakland Raiders</option>
    <option>San Diego Chargers</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why nobody suggested the right way of doing this. Just set the paramter `include_group_label_in_selected` to `true` when initializing the plugin. You will get

**<OptGroupLabel> : <OptionText>**

in the selected option.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with multiple selects and also fixes the label when deselecting:

```
    $('select').chosen().filter('[multiple]').on('change', function(event, el) {
    var value = el.selected ? el.selected : el.deselected;
    var option = $(this).find("option[value=" + value + "]");
    var currentText = option.text();
    var newText;
    if (el.selected) {
      var optgroupLabel = option.closest('optgroup').attr('label');
      newText = optgroupLabel + ' - ' + currentText;
    } else {
      newText = currentText.split(' - ')[1];
    }
    option.text(newText).trigger("chosen:updated");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To make **optgroups** with cakephp you have to **make array** like this way.
I.e

```
$counties = array(
  'Country Name 1' => array(
    'county_1_id' => 'County 1 Name',
    'county_2_id' => 'County 2 Name',
    'county_3_id' => 'County 3 Name',
  ),
  'Country Name 2' => array(
    'county_4_id' => 'County 4 Name',
    'county_5_id' => 'County 5 Name',
    'county_6_id' => 'County 6 Name',
  ),
);

echo $this->Form->input('country', array('type' => 'select', 'options' => $counties));
```