# Redesigning <select>'s Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to style a dropdown according to this tutorial: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/wp-content/uploads/examples/reinventing-drop-down/Select2DropDown.html

Everything works fine. However I was wondering how to make it work if there are optgroups in the select tag. I'm new to Javascript and have little experience. Could anyone explain how this could be possibly done, please? I don't quite get it how to get the data from the optgroup to be displayed in the list.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to create non-selectable dividers with labels (functionality similar to optgroup), you could append a div tag to the list with label text inside it. It may not be standard or best practice for list elements but it works cross-browser.

```
<ul>
  <div><b><font color="black">Optgroup Title</font></b></div>
  <li><a href="#">Option 1<span class="value">1</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fvLyebgu/1/

If you need code to obtain the optgroup in JavaScript, [that's been answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10093048/jquery-get-label-of-optgroup-of-select-option).